# Problem while installing Ubuntu 14.04 from USB drive

Tags: iso, md5sum, startup-disk-creator

I have recently downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 iso file via torrent. After downloading, I checked the MD5 sum of the downloaded .iso file and it was correct. Then I created bootable USB drive using the Startup Disk Creator application.

I tried to find the MD5 sum using the command `md5sum /dev/sdc1` but the terminal returned `md5sum: /dev/sdc1: Permission denied`. I am attaching the snapshot of the permissions tab of my USB drive to help you guys figure out what's wrong.

[image: Permissions tab of USB drive]

**Update 1:** I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 from that USB drive. But only a black screen showed up with the message `Boot Error`. Why is this happening? What should I do to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Same way you checked the iso

```
md5sum /dev/sdb1
```

change sdb1 to your flash drive.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM for additional information.